# Como fazer o Tkinter aguardar interação do usuário durante o script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estou aprendendo Python por conta própria e agora peguei pra aprender GUI em Tkinter. Se alguém puder me ajudar, estou com dificuldade em fazer com que o programa exiba uma saudação e então ofereça opções em diferentes botões. Aliás... Acho que consegui fazer isso, mas o problema é que eu queria que o programa esperasse o usuário interagir para só então executar a próxima linha.

Digamos por exemplo que eu crie um arquivo com a classe Janela (para a interface) e algumas funções (Janela.py):

```py
import time
from tkinter import *

# Aqui a função dos botões. Referenciei ela primeiro para não dar conflito. Quando tentei isso, quebrei esse código em mais de um programa e chamei as funções de lá, mas aqui vou fazer tudo em um arquivo só para não ficar confuso:    

Escolha = ''

def Escolher(X):
    Escolha = X


# Aqui o objeto 'Janela':

class Janela:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Janela = Tk()
        self.Janela.title = 'Interaja'
        self.Janela.minsize = (500, 300)
        # Aqui uma label para imprimir as mensagens que quero passar para o usuário:  
        self.Texto = Label(self.Janela, text = '')
        self.Texto.pack()
        # Aqui uma série de botões:
        self.B1 = Button(self.Janela, text = 'Opção 1', command = Escolher('1'))
        self.B1.pack()
        self.B2 = Button(self.Janela, text = 'Opção 2', command = Escolher('2'))
        self.B2.pack()
        self.B3 = Button(self.Janela, text = 'Opção 3', command = Escolher('3'))
        self.B3.pack()

# Aqui crio uma instância do objeto Janela:  

Exemplo = Janela()

# Aqui uma função para que determinadas mensagens sejam exibidas:  

def Diga(X):
    Exemplo.Texto.configure(text = X)
    Exemplo.Texto.update()
    time.sleep(3) # Ignorem. Deixei esse atraso pro usuário conseguir ler a tempo. Tenho um método mais eficiente pra isso, mas só pra simplificar deixei assim.  

# Por fim, a parte principal do programa:  

Diga('Sejam bem-vindos!')
Diga('Você quer escolher qual opção?')
EspereEscolha() # Aqui, queria que o programa esperasse a opção ser escolhida para só então imprimir a seguinte mensagem:  
Diga('Você escolheu a opção {}'.format(Escolha))
Texte.mainloop()
```

Alguém por um acaso sabe me explicar como faço pra criar esse 'EspereEscolha()', ou se ele já existe e eu é quem não estou sabendo fazer?

Grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

é o seguinte, quando você cria um Tk() você tem que declarar o mainloop dele

```
Texte.mainloop()
```

o que acontece é que você chamando uma função que vem antes desse mainloop meio que nunca vai funcionar o input do usuário pelo tkinter, já que você não tá rodando de fato o loop da interface. Você precisa criar então a sua classe de forma que ela tenha os métodos e você vai chamando ela a partir do **init** do objeto. Isso para tudo na verdade, desda criação dos widgets até os comandos referentes a eles. Eu reescrevi o seu código com essas mudanças para te mostrar como poderia ser

```
import time
from tkinter import *

class Janela:

def __init__(self):
    self.Janela = Tk()
    self.Janela.title = 'Interaja'
    self.Janela.minsize = (500, 300)
    # Aqui uma label para imprimir as mensagens que quero passar para o usuário:  
    self.Texto = Label(self.Janela, text = '')
    self.Texto.pack()
    self.Apresentacao()

# A apresentação que você queria que o usuário pudesse ler.
# tenha em mente que o sleep para o processo total, logo o tkinter vai dar aquele sinalzin de carregamento
# se alguem passar o mouse por cima do GUI. Talvez você pode fazer uma validação futura
# pegando o time atual e salvando o valor, validando se ele é menor que o tempo futuro, como um cooldown
def Apresentacao(self):
    self.Diga('Sejam bem-vindos!')
    time.sleep(3)
    self.Diga('Você quer escolher qual opção?')
    time.sleep(3)
    self.MostarOpcoes()

# método que pode ser chamado em qualquer outra função para alterar um label especifico
# talvez fazer um método mais genérico onde você passa qual label especifica você quer alterar
def Diga(self, texto):
    self.Texto.configure(text = texto)
    self.Texto.update()

# outra função para mostrar widgets enquanto o frame esta no mainloop.
def MostarOpcoes(self):
    # esse lambda é uma gambiarrazinha para passar um valor para uma função
    # geralmente se não utilizar alguma técnica do tipo para por uma função no command
    # faz com que a função seja chamada na hora de instanciar o objeto, então toma cuidado com o command
    self.B1 = Button(self.Janela, text = 'Opção 1', command = lambda valor=1: self.Escolher(valor))
    self.B1.pack()
    self.B2 = Button(self.Janela, text = 'Opção 2', command = lambda valor=2: self.Escolher(valor))
    self.B2.pack()
    self.B3 = Button(self.Janela, text = 'Opção 3', command = lambda valor=3: self.Escolher(valor))
    self.B3.pack()
# função que os botões utilizam
def Escolher(self, valor):
    self.Diga('Você escolheu a opção {}'.format(valor))

Exemplo = Janela()

Exemplo.Janela.mainloop()
```

Então só pra recapitular, faça métodos que sejam utilizados durante a execução do mainloop do frame, porque qualquer coisa que você escrever abaixo da linha do mainloop() só irá ser executada depois de fechar o tkinter e qualquer coisa a cima do mainloop() não executara nada do GUI do tkinter :3